# How to give diagnostic actions listDatabases to a user in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, openshift

I'm trying to connect from a java application to a mongodb database in openshift and I'm having some trouble with roles and actions allowed.

I run the rch port-forward command like so:

```
rhc port-forward -a test
```

it all goes great and I'm able to connect to the database using:

```
mongo admin -u admin -p '*******' --host 127.0.0.1 --port 44506
```

and I can execute commands like:

```
> use test
> show databases
```

But if i connect directly to my database using:

```
mongo test -u admin -p '*******' --host 127.0.0.1 --port 44506
```

I'm unable to run the show databases command

```
listDatabases failed:{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
```

How can i give action listDatabases to this user in this database?

I found this page in the mongodb documentation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#security-user-actions
Which talks about Diagnostic Actions but does not mention how to give such action to a user.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you ssh into your application and run the mongodb shell as that user, can you execute that command?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by wdberkeley, you have to have a user in the `admin` database with the ability to list databases.

To do this, you first have to create a very minimal "role" for this user allowing them to list databases, and then create a user with both this role and the role for reading and writing your other database:

```js
use admin

db.runCommand({ createRole: "listDatabases",
    privileges: [
        { resource: { cluster : true }, actions: ["listDatabases"]}
    ],
    roles: []
})

db.createUser({
    user: "<userName>",
    pwd: "<passwd>",
    roles: [
        { role: "readWrite", db: "test" },
        { role: "listDatabases", db: "admin" }
    ]
})
```

The MongoDB documentation has references for both [`createRole`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createRole/#dbcmd.createRole) and [`createUser`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/#db.createUser), if you want to learn more about these commands.

Comment: I'm unable to run the createRole command, I suspect it has something to do with mongodb version, openshift is currently on 2.4.9... and This is 2.6.x... I'm getting "no such cmd: createRole".

Answer (score 4):

You're logging in as two different users. Users are scoped by namespace, so user John who lives in `test` is not the same as user John who lives in `admin`, though both Johns may have rights in the `test` database. I think this much you may already understand, but I wanted to clarify it just in case.

I don't believe you can give a user scoped to a non-`admin` database the `listDatabases` action in a privilege because the `listDatabases` action must go with the `cluster` resource (`listDatabases` is a cluster-wide sort of operation), and a privilege with a `cluster` resource can only be scoped to a role on the `admin` database. Cutting out the jargon of MongoDB's authorization model, a non-`admin` database user can't use `listDatabases` because it's a cluster-wide operation and only `admin` database users should be able to do cluster-wide things.

Comment: That raises a problem. Because I'm using the Java driver to connect and it needs at some point to execute the {listDatabases: 1} command. And as obvious I'm not giving him Administrator privileges to the full database.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.12.4/com/mongodb/Mongo.java#389

Comment: You don't need to give admin privileges to the user. You just need to create the user on the `admin` database so he can receive special multi-database privileges like a `listDatabases` privilege. You can have a user that can list all the databases but only insert, update, or find on one database.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do it or direct me to a place where it explains how to do this?
I'm new to all the mongodb world.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add the approach mentioned by i80and works on MongoDB 3.2.3

1. create custom role that contain listDatabase and specify cluster:true, I did it when specify resource as db, it doesn't work
2. grant this role to user
   Note: make sure you are connected to the correct db when performing security task because you will need to be authenticated using this specific db where the user is created